# Clean up orphaned documents in MongoDB error

Tags: mongodb

While trying to clean `cleanupOrphaned`  in my cluster [image]

I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you confirm your MongoDB server version with `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell? Are you connected to a `mongos` or a `mongod`?

Comment: I guess that you are using mongodb 2.4 version, what didn't have `cleanupOrphaned` command, yet. If not, at least you have one error. That `panelist_id` should be `panelist_id.collection`, if panelist_id is database.

Comment: My vesrion is 3.4.3 i have tried with transam_db.panelist (as my database.colection) but i am finding the same error message as (no such cmd: cleanupOrphaned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK..

Step 1. database and collection must be originally created (or sharded) thru mongoS

Step 2. command `db.runCommand({cleanupOrphaned: "test.collection"})` must be ran on individual shard node (if replica set, then primary) at admin database. Not on mongoS, if you run that command on mongoS, you get that error message (and of course that error don't tell you that mongos cannot support that command).

```
#>mlaunch init --sharded 2 --single
launching: mongod on port 27018
launching: mongod on port 27019
launching: config server on port 27020
replica set 'configRepl' initialized.
launching: mongos on port 27017
adding shards.

#>mongo --port 27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> use test
switched to db test
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.collection.insert({})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

#> mongo --port 27018 
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
MongoDB > use admin
switched to db admin
MongoDB > db.runCommand( {cleanupOrphaned: "test.collection"})
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: what is the procedure to run it from mongos

Comment: You cannot run it in the mongos. It must be run at every shard individually. If you try to run, you get error message as you did.

Comment: ..but you can of course create connection from mongos to individual replica set primary and run command then. Result is same.

Comment: while runnig the above command in my cluster i am getting rs1:primary>db.runCommand( {cleanupOrphaned: "tans.panelist"})
{"stoppedAtKey" : { "panelist_id : 38112 }, "ok' : 1}      
rs2:primary>db.runCommand( {cleanupOrphaned: "tans.panelist"})
{"stoppedAtKey" : { "panelist_id : 28741 }, "ok' : 1} is this the correct result

Comment: Yes, result is OK:1, so command was successful.

Comment: can you give me example for starting from key to end key for orphaned document

Comment: Check code (Remove All Orphaned Documents from a Shard) from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/cleanupOrphaned/